# Can I use swift code to create a Desktop Linux App?

Tags: swift, linux, desktop

I developed an app for iOS in Swift, and now I have to make the same app in Linux.

I know that in Linux I can't use frameworks as UIKit. What are the better alternatives?

I found different projects that provides a graphic UI:

- Swift for GUI

  https://www.reddit.com/r/swift/comments/4ig0ic/swift_for_linux_and_graphical_interface/
- Qt Swift

  https://github.com/Longhanks/qlift

  minesweeper in Qt: https://github.com/Longhanks/swiftmine
- Pure Swift

  https://github.com/PureSwift
- Cacao Lib: https://github.com/PureSwift/Cacao

Did you try them? Are there better options?

Other way could be to create a Framework or DLL with my Swift code and use other language to develop the Linux Desktop app. Is this possible?